# ZK Zats not working (EmulatorException)

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, zk

I'm doing a ZK application that uses Hibernate to access a database. I'm trying to do JUnit tests following [this example](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZATS%20Essentials/Getting%20Started/First%20Mimic%20Test%20Case/JUnit%20Example), but I get this error on the JUnit view:

```
org.zkoss.zats.mimic.impl.emulator.EmulatorException: 
at org.zkoss.zats.mimic.impl.emulator.JettyEmulator.<init>(JettyEmulator.java:143)
at org.zkoss.zats.mimic.impl.emulator.EmulatorBuilder.create(EmulatorBuilder.java:130)
at org.zkoss.zats.mimic.DefaultZatsEnvironment.init(DefaultZatsEnvironment.java:86)
at org.zkoss.zats.mimic.Zats.init(Zats.java:46)
at br.ufjf.tcc.controller.LoginControllerTest.init(LoginControllerTest.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

And this error on Console:

```
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
```

By the way, are there better tools to test ZK applications?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in an Eclipse WTP project with Tomcat 6 as the server runtime. It seems to me that the Jetty server provided by ZATS conflicts with Tomcat.

Execute the tests without the Tomcat libs in the classpath, and everything works fine.